# how to subtract Sub-Report group from main report group in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

Sub Report formula

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar exp_credit:= Sum ({Exp_credit.amount}, {Exp_credit.date}, "monthly"
```

Sub Report value

```
04/2014    1500
05/2014    2000
06/2014    1500
07/2014    1000
08/2014    3000
09/2014    4000
10/2014    3500
11/2014    2800
12/2014    2600
01/2015    2800
02/2015    2800
03/2015    2600
```

Main Report formula

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar exp_debit:= Sum ({Exp_debit.amount}, {Exp_debit.date}, "monthly"
```

Main Report value

```
04/2014    3500
05/2014    3500
06/2014    3000
07/2014    4000
08/2014    3900
09/2014    3900
10/2014    4000
11/2014    5000
12/2014    2800
01/2015    3500
02/2015    3700
03/2015    3700
```

Net formula

```
whileprintingrecords; 
shared numbervar exp_credit;
shared numbervar exp_debit; 
shared numbervar net:= (exp_debit-exp_credit);
```

I am getting net formula value

```
04/2014    900
05/2014    900
06/2014    400
07/2014   1400
08/2014   1300
09/2014   1300
10/2014   1400
11/2014   2400
12/2014    200
01/2015    900
02/2015   1100
03/2015   1100
```

I think sub report last value 2600 is deducted for each month and I need each month value separately please help me.

Comment: Where did you place sub report and where did you place main report? In which section?

Comment: Sub report formula @exp_credit is placed in sub report's group header#1 section,  and sub report is placed on main report in report header section. All values are correctly calculated. Sub report last value 2600 is deducted for each month and I need each month value separately. Please help me asap. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please answer my question, waiting your reply please.....

Comment: Your implementation is very confusing....it's better to use arrays...have you tried using those....let me know...again in main report where did you place the main report values

Comment: Why are you using sub report....i dont see any use...from  how many tables are you getting debit and credit values

Comment: Nearly 30 to 40 tables. If apply direct formula I can't get correct result. please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: In main report I placed main report value in group header#1 and it nearly 30 to 40 tables. If apply direct formula I can't get correct result. please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: All the stuff you are doing in sub report...do in main report and check the values.....if you can post the report screen shot and tables screen shot will help

Comment: I am unable to use in single report and need sub report then let me know

Comment: I can't attach my screen shots, how do it.

Comment: There is option to attach the image use that....if that is not available then you can post the link that takes to image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below approach:

Create 2 sub reports for debit and credit and place one by one in header. Store all values of debit in array and all values of credit in array and pass both to main report.

Use below code to store values in array.

```
Shared StringVar array store;

store:=store+ (Date&"-"&ToText(Value)); 
//append date and value to retrieve correctly in main report
1
```

Create same formula in both sub reports with different shared variable

In main report

```
Shared Stringvar Store //assume debit value
Shared stringvar store1 //assume credit

//now split and convert to number and subtract the values
```

Tonumber( Split(Store[1],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[1],"-")[2] )

Take care you subtract similar dates

This will give you difference of first value..in the same way change the numbers in store and store 1 braces to get values for other values

Comment: Siva, thanks for your timely support. If I use this formula am getting error message "the result of a formula cannot be an array". How to solve it. Sorry for this delay reply.

Comment: There are two formulas which formula are you talking about...also i checked there shouldnt be that error appearing

Comment: original formula is --> Shared StringVar array store;
store:=store+ (Date&"-"&ToText(Value));     my applied formula is  --->  Shared StringVar array store;
store:=store+ (GroupName ({Exp_debit.date}, "monthly")&"-"&ToText(Sum ({Exp_debit.amount}, {Exp_debit.date}, "monthly"))); please let me if I have any mistakes

Comment: Have you added 1 after semicolon...add it also editing the solution a bit

Comment: I applied main report formula as ---> Shared Stringvar Store
Shared stringvar store1

Tonumber( Split(Store,[1]"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[1],"-")[2] ) but got error message " The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.

Comment: Yes you are right, if i corrected it  --->error message [The ) is missing"] with selection on "-" . How to solve it.

Comment: Edited answer check and let me know

Comment: I got error message while run report it is placed on detail section --> [A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array] with selection on ( Split(Store[1],"-")[1] ).

Comment: In each value are date and value concatinated or there is only one value

Comment: Post the format of your values in array...how those look like

Comment: Please find below my output format 04/2014    2000
05/2014    1500
06/2014    1500
07/2014      300
08/2014      900
09/2014     -100
10/2014      500
11/2014    2200
12/2014      200
01/2015      700
02/2015      900
03/2015    1100

Comment: - should be between every value that is 04/2014-2000 should be one value in the array like wise all values and in both the sub reports where did you place the concatination formula

Comment: Now it works thank you so much, there is no word to explain my expression, you save my job really you are genius. You are doing great job thank you for your valuable support and I need all 12 or more values should print based on input dates. How is it possible to print all data line by line.

Comment: You can create 12 formulas or you can use line break in single formula and display 12 values...line break can be achieved by `chrW(13)`

Comment: Can you please guide how to use line break in formula.

Comment: Dear Siva, Can you please guide how to use line break in formula. If i do get error message only. waiting your answer please...

Comment: Sure let me know if you get a error message...will post resolution

Comment: My output formula is -->  Shared Stringvar array Store;
Shared stringvar array store1;
Tonumber( Split(Store[1],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[1],"-")[2] )+
chrw(13)+
Tonumber( Split(Store[2],"-")[3]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[2],"-")[3] ) if I save it (A number, currency amount, date, time, or date-time is required here with selection on chrw(13).

Comment: I have done it while run report error message--> A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array.

Comment: Its a generic error....without seeing exact code it is difficult to tell but will tell you how to debug the issue

Comment: Count all the rows in array. Now array starts from 1 now take care in you code in array subscript your value should never exceed the count of array...for eg if total elements in array is 10 then if you subscript is 11 this will throw error

Comment: First formula--> Shared StringVar array store;
store:=store+ (GroupName ({Exp_debit.date}, "monthly")&"-"&ToText(Sum ({Exp_debit.amount}, {Exp_debit.date}, "monthly"))); 1
Second formula--> Shared StringVar array store1;
store1:=store1+ (GroupName ({Exp_credit.date}, "monthly")&"-"&ToText(Sum ({Exp_credit.amount}, {Exp_credit.date}, "monthly"))); 1 output formula --> Shared Stringvar array Store;
Shared stringvar array store1;
Tonumber( Split(Store[1],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[1],"-")[2])
&chrw(13)& 
Tonumber( Split(Store[2],"-")[3]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[2],"-")[3])

Comment: Tonumber( Split(Store[2],"-")[3]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[2],"-")[3] this is wrong

Comment: Tonumber( Split(Store[2],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[2],"-")[2]....this is correct.....store sub script will increase not other

Comment: If i use formula ---> Shared Stringvar array Store;
Shared stringvar array store1;
Tonumber( Split(Store[1],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[1],"-")[2])
&chrw(13)& 
Tonumber( Split(Store[2],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[2],"-")[2])
&chrw(13)& 
Tonumber( Split(Store[3],"-")[3]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[3],"-")[3])
am getting same error while run the report -->  A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array

Comment: Dont blindly follow try to understand logic..Tonumber( Split(Store[3],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[3],"-")[2]...in the same wayTonumber( Split(Store[4],"-")[2]) - Tonumber(Split(Store1[4],"-")[2]

Comment: sorry bro.... now I corrected it. But I get first value of 04/2014 2000 only not getting other line items.

Comment: Yes, values in array is printing horizontally, not printing line by line.

Comment: Hi Siva, thanks for your support it works good.  Please give solution for following, 1) Is it possible to make chart based on the above formula because chart option is disabled for this formula. 2) How to increase more than 12 values of array, please...

Comment: We didnt define any size for the array so array will accomodate any number of values for chart start a new question....comments have become very lenghty..